# Why does the output stay 0 and -1, regardless the input?

Tags: java, search

I'm new to java and im trying to write a program that gets an undefined amount of integers and tells you the longest order of the same integer.

```
public class Search{
  public static void main(String args[]){


    int order[] = new int[args.length];
    for(int i = 0;i < args.length;i++){        //Input into array
      order[i] = Integer.parseInt(args[i]);
    }
    int count = 0;
    int temp_count = 0;
    int pos = -1;
    int temp_pos = -1;
    boolean search = false;

    for(int i = 1; i < args.length;i++){
      if(order[i-1] != order[i]){
        temp_count = 1;                    //line of the same integers?
        search = true;
        temp_pos++;
      } else if(search && order[i-1] == order[i]){ // How long is the line?
          temp_count++;
      } else if(search && order[i-1] != order[i]){ // Does the line end?
          if (temp_count > count){
            count = temp_count;             // Update old length and position
            pos = temp_pos;
          }
          search = false;
      }
    }
    System.out.println("length: " + count);    //output
    System.out.println("position " + pos);
  }
}
```

The output is 0 and -1 , what should only be the case if there is no order of the same integers.

Comment: [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173)

Answer (score 2):

In your `if` statement you are **checking twice** the same condition in the `if` and in the `else if`.
And this condition will never happen:

```
} else if(search && order[i-1] != order[i]){
```

In this way all variables remain `count = 0;` and `pos = -1;`

```
  if(order[i-1] != order[i]){
    //...
  } else if(search && order[i-1] != order[i]){ 
    // never run!! 
    //...
    count = temp_count;     
    pos = temp_pos;  
  }
```

Comment: Ty for your help. I realised, that i dont need the first if statement and could just use the second statement to verify if its an order.